# Stop iframe redirect/opening mobile safari in phonegap project

Tags: iphone, ios, iframe, cordova

Currently I have been loading a page into a hidden iframe within my phonegap project as a way of scraping data off a mobile version of a website I use within my app.

The problem is that one particular site has some type of frame buster and sends a redirect which exits the app and loads the page in mobile safari.

Is there a way to stop the reload ? 
Leaving the ethics of scraping aside :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer in this post 
http://craigpfau.com/2012/02/phonegap-ios-uiwebview-and-safari-app-links/

Replace this in the AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL) webView:(UIWebView*)theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest: (NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
   NSURL *url = [request URL];

   if ([[url absoluteString] rangeOfString:@"URLToOpenInUIWebView.com"].location != NSNotFound) {
      return YES;
   }
   else {
      return [self.viewController webView:theWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:request navigationType:navigationType];
   }
}
```

Any links you don't want to open in UIwebview you use target="_blank"

Answer (score 17):

If you're using PhoneGap Build, add this to your `config.xml` file:

```
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="true" />
```

If you're not using Build set this in your `Cordova.plist/Phongap.plist`:

```
OpenAllWhitelistURLsInWebView = 'Yes'
```

Comment: I'm not building through PG build. Can I do this option otherwise ?

Comment: Yeah, I'm looking for the syntax.

Comment: Thanks @ThinkingStiff I don't have that option but I think its because I'm on the rather stable PG 1.4.1.. I might have to transfer to Cordova at some point

Comment: @AdamWare I'm using PhoneGap 1.8.1.