# Phonegap redirecting to safari

Tags: ios, cordova, redirect

I'm trying to use Phonegap to build an iOS application through github. All I have in my directory is one html file and an image. The html basically redirects them to my website, which is optimized for mobile devices. However, instead of redirecting them in-app, it opens a safari window and tries to load my website in there. How do I get it to load the website in-app?

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be useless to correct youut code, because Apple won't allow you to bring this app into the store. It is not allowed create just a browser. But this may answer your question: [Stop iframe redirect/opening mobile safari in phonegap project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11271020/stop-iframe-redirect-opening-mobile-safari-in-phonegap-project)